# Restrict Edge evergreen version to s specific version

Tags: c++, microsoft-edge, webview2

We create an `evergreen WebView2` environment with CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions.

The current used version I see is `120.0.2210.61` (taken from the file `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp\<prog>\BrowserData\EBWebView\Last Version`)

Now it seams that we have problems when a WebView2 control is destroyed, that this has strange side effects on other COM controls we use. When I have details for that I will ask another question.

Question: Is there a way to restrict the used version to a specific version. In other words to force the WebView2 to a specific version?

Background: Some customers show specific COM errors when closing views sing the WebView2. The customers use program version that run for 3 years and no update was performed in the last 2 years! Also we can see that Windows Updates are not current.

Because of the age of the installed software we can say that the update of the WebView2 component was installed after Saturday evening.

I can repro the error on my machine with the lastest updates and our new program version.

So for a fast fix and test, it would be nice to know if there is a way to use an older WebView2 evergreen component to validate if the reason is really the new WebView2 update. **Also this might help the customers now!**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#the-fixed-version-runtime-distribution-mode

Comment: This doesn't help. I understand the distribution modes, But software is already shipped and running. Years ago the decision was made to use "evergreen". I can change the next version to use a fixed version. But for now I need to know if I can change the existing delivered software to use an older WV2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use a specific version of the webview2 runtime, you should use the fixed version runtime instead of the evergreen version. Because the evergreen version is automatically updated by design, you need the fixed version to control it. Please refer to this doc: [The Fixed Version runtime distribution mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#the-fixed-version-runtime-distribution-mode).

Downloading the fixed version based on official channels only provides the 2 latest versions, so if you need to download and install older versions of the webview2 runtime, you can check if the version you need here:https://github.com/westinyang/WebView2RuntimeArchive/releases?page=1

Comment: This doesn't help. I understand the distribution modes, But software is already shipped and running. Years ago the decision was made to use "evergreen". I can change the next version to use a fixed version. But for now I need to know if I can change the existing delivered software to use an older WV2 version.

Comment: In my opinion, WebView2 runtime updates are for compatibility with new APIs and security updates. I think this will be feasible when the fixed version of webView2 runtime you choose is already compatible with all feature/APIs within the application.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the code it is possible to redirect even an everygreen WebView2 installation to an older version. But this version must be installed on the local machine.

- Download an older version from the corresponding GitHub page or the WebView2 configuration page.
- Extract it to a local folder on the current maschine
- Add an entry for the program or under "*" in the registry entry tree `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\WebView2\BrowserExecutableFolder`. Add the path of the installed version in the value field. (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-webview-policies)

You can also use the HKCU hive.

For 32bit programs the regisry entry is located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\WebView2\BrowserExecutableFolder`